# Erro número 1064 CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Um erro está aparecendo quando vou logar no meu sistema:

> Error Number: 1064
>
> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'SET `last_activity` = 1445537033, `user_data` =
>   'a:5:{s:9:\"user_data\";s:0:\"\"' at line 1
>
> ```
> UPDATE SET `last_activity` = 1445537033,
>            `user_data` = 'a:5:{s:9:\"user_data\";s:0:\"\";s:7:\"user_id\";s:1:\"1\";s:9:\"user_nome\";s:15:\"Sergio Henrique\";s:10:\"user_admin\";s:1:\"1\";s:11:\"user_logado\";b:1;}'
> WHERE `session_id` = 'fa6f6e8bb9106a277ff5373f8301cac1'
> ```
>
> Filename: libraries/Session.php
>
> Line Number: 306

Estava funcionando antes, o que fazer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faltou especificar o nome da tabela `UPDATE tabela SET`